# How to check for existing image id and hide subsequently generated identical ones

Tags: jquery, ajax, unique-id

I have an Ajax request, with a success function that returns the images that have been uploaded for a certain asset. The issue is that if I upload a SQUARE image, and then upload a PORTRAIT or LANDSCAPE, it will display the same image again.

I have created a variable which generates a unique id(current date/time) and sets that as the id of each image. How can I check to make sure that an image is already on the page, and if so, not display an identical one with the same id?

```
success: function(response){
    var random = Date.now();
    var r = JSON.stringify(response);
    var obj = $.parseJSON(r);
    for (var property in obj.entity.entries) {
        if (obj.entity.entries.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            $(".response").append($("<li><img id='" + random + "'width='100' height='100' src='" + obj.entity.entries[property].uri + "'/></img><p>" + obj.entity.entries[property].orientation + "</p></li>"));
        }
    }
    $(".share-link").html("<div class='alert alert-success'><p>Success! " + imageid.value +" was posted.</p></div>");
}
```

So instead of returning `SQUARE` orientation, uploading another image and returning `SQUARE`, `SQUARE`, `PORTRAIT`, I need to be able to only return a single instance of each(checking to see if one already exists).

**CLARIFICATION: The logic should be as follows**

If an image with orientation of either SQUARE(`<p>SQUARE</p>`) / PORTRAIT(`<p>PORTRAIT</p>`) / LANDSCAPE(`<p>LANDSCAPE</p>`) exists in the `.result` div, then hide subsequent loading SQUARE/PORTRAIT/LANDSCAPE images that load.

Comment: Why do you call `JSON.stringify` and then `JSON.parse`? That equivalent to `var obj = response`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a jQuery selector that searches for the `src=X` property.

```
$.each(obj.entity.entries, function(i, e) {
    if ($("img[src='" + e.uri + "'").length == 0) {
        $(".response").append($("<li><img id='" + random + "'width='100' height='100' src='" + e.uri + "'/></img><p>" + e.orientation + "</p></li>"));
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't hide images that are already in the system for the associated asset. When the user submits an image, the success callback returns the images (square/portrait/landscape) that the associated asset already has.

Comment: What's the difference between hiding the images that are already there and not loading the duplicate image?

Comment: See the solution I posted below. I'm clearing the `.results` div before loading the images from the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue is that you have no space between your 'id' and 'width' attributes above. Try this:

```
 $(".response").append($("<li><img id='" + random + "' width='100' height='100' src='" + obj.entity.entries[property].uri + "'/></img><p>" + obj.entity.entries[property].orientation + "</p></li>"));
```

Also, it's possible for you to store references to the DOM element itself of the image, rather than just the ID, for later use in callbacks, etc. For example, you may find [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) useful for this.

---

But, a possible alternative solution to generating these yourself, if you need to use an id, could be to use [`.uniqueId()`](https://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/) from jQuery UI. For example:

```
var img = $("<img>", {width: 100, height: 100, src: '#'});
img.uniqueId();
console.log(img);
var li = img.wrap("<li></li>").parent();
li.append($("<p></p>").text("Added IMG w/ ID: " + img[0].id));
$(".results").append(li);
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8u7px73a/4/

Comment: You don't have to have a space after the closing quote of an attribute, the quote acts as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was much easier: just needed to clear the `.reponse` div `$(".response").clear();`on each submission, so the images returned were new and not duplicates.

```
success: function(response){
    var random = Date.now();
    var obj = response;
    $(".response").empty();
    for (var property in obj.entity.entries) {
         if (obj.entity.entries.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
             $(".response").append($("<li><img id='" + random + "' width='100' height='100' src='" + obj.entity.entries[property].uri + "'/></img><p>" + obj.entity.entries[property].orientation + "</p></li>"));
         }
    }
         $(".share-link").html("<div class='alert alert-success'><p>Success! " + imageid.value +" was posted.</p></div>");
}
```